# issue with going back to PARENT_ACTIVITY in manifest, using setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have two java files, `NewContact` and `ViewContact`.

In both of them my code goes something like this, which works in `NewContact`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_contact);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //show the App title
    actionbar.setTitle("MyApp");

    }

//code for the '<', back button. Go back to PopulistoListView, as defined
//in Manifest, PARENT_ACTIVITY
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my `manifest` (from `<application>` to `</application>`)goes like this:

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.VerifyUserPhoneNumber"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.DisplayMyPopulistoListView"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.PopulistoListView"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.CountryCodes" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.ViewContact"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.PopulistoListView" />

        <activity android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.EditContact" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.NewContact"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.PopulistoListView" />
        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
```

Yet when I click the `'<'` button in `ViewContact` I get the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity ViewContact does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(NavUtils.java:178)
                                                                                      at com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.ViewContact.onOptionsItemSelected(ViewContact.java:405)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2681)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:403)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:189)
```

Yet, you can see I do have a `parent activity` defined in my `Manifest`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so what `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` doing, seeing as it is referenced in the stacktrace, would be handy to post that relevant code. Also if you've defined that parent activity you shouldn't even need to force navigating back i.e no need to do anything in `onOptionsItemSelected` it should go back on the task stack itself.

Comment: `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)`? I think it just goes up to the parent activity, defined in the manifest - which is the activity I want it to go back/up to. Strange the way it works in one activity, `NewContact`, and not the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at your manifest, specifically this part:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.ViewContact"
        android:noHistory="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.PopulistoListView" />
```

You'll see that you close the `<activity>` tag **before** the `<meta-data>` element, which means the `<meta-data>` is associated with the whole `<application>` object (which is valid, but not what you want).

Update your manifest so that the `<meta-data>` element is within the `<activity>` element:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.ViewContact"
        android:noHistory="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.PopulistoListView" />
 </activity>
```